# What is the benefit of using lodash assign function?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to understand the benefit of using the lodash `assign` method instead of normal javascript.

I have one object with some properties and I want to add one more property to it with some value like:

```
 var employee = {name: 'John'}
```

Now I want to add one more property, e.g., age with value 25. So in normal Javascript i could do:

```
employee.age = 25;
```

and this will add the new property to the `employee` object with the value `25`. This could also be done via lodash `assign`:

```
_.assign(employee, {age: 25})
```

What is the benefit of using lodash here instead of normal javascript? Is it just a matter of preference, and both ways are fine?

Comment: You should probably never use it to simply set another property, as in your example. It's meant for use when you're copying a large, potentially variable, set of properties from one object to another.

Comment: Like Jeremy said, it's a convenience function for times you're assigning multiple properties. It handles applying them in the correct order, overwriting if necessary, etc.

Comment: Also, sometimes you want to assign properties from an arbitrary object that may come with different number of properties. This method is useful to keep things clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As comments have stated, it's designed for use for en masse assignment / object extension.
It actually does a fair amount more - for example, you can define a function to customise values as they are assigned.

Note also `_.extend(...)` is an alias to this method.

Lodash docs for your reference https://lodash.com/docs#assign

The advantage over plain Javascript is... the plain Javascript is written and optimised for you :) aka convenience with a little DRY mixed in for good measure.